# corresponding system libraries on mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu

I need to run a command on mac which is made for Ubuntu. the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython-dev lib32ncurses5-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev lib32z1-dev libjpeg-dev libpq-dev
```

I need to find the corresponding names for mac. Any suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: `brew search curses`, `brew search xslt`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `brew`, here: http://brew.sh/

Brew is a package manager for OS X and will allow you to install all your dependency packages.

The names won't match up exactly, and you'll have to find the brew equivalencies, but this is generally how most devs manage packages on OS X.

Comment: I have Brew installed. My problem is finding the equivalent names